# Nswag - message in attribute "obsolete" is not exist in the generated client

Tags: nswag

I use Nswag for generate clients.
In my controller method marked as [Obsolete("Reason")] but in generated client for it 'obsolete' attribute without comment. [System.Obsolete] and clients is not see reason why this method deprecated.

Is there a way around this problem?

In .nswag config "ignoreObsoleteProperties": false

Comment: The attribute is generated but without comment? If so then it is because swagger specs can only describe obsolete but not a reason

Comment: Thanks for your answer, are there any workarounds?

Comment: Custom schema properties and a client generator extension.